# how to disable combobox in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have created ComboBox and CheckBox in a Form.
Now what I want to do is, if I checked that CheckBox means the ComboBox will be disabled. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set disable the `ComboBox` when the `CheckBox` is checked. You must put this code inside the `actionPerformed` method, when you capture a `FIRE` key pressed for example. So:

```
  if(checkBox.isSelected()){
       comboBox.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
       comboBox.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: You need to accept his answer which is correct (see the check you should have next to the answer)